# jquery autocomeplete plugin not working with numeric values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to show stock number suggestions in a search box.
So I tried using the Jquery autocomplete plugin. I am making an ajax call to a function inside my cfc which returns all the
stock numbers in an array.

But the problem is my search box is not showing the suggestions properly. I think this issue is because of numeric values.
Any one faced the issue? Here is a replica:

```js
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      1234,
      1456,
      1789,
      1988,  
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

```html
 <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
    
</body>
```

The same is working fine with string data.How to fix it?

Comment: Here auto-complete is not transforming `numeric source` to `string search text`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in autocomplete [jQueryUI docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

There are two supported formats of array

> Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported
>   formats:
>
> - An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> - An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label:    "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

Try following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "1234",
    "1456",
    "1789",
    "1988",  
  ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
});
```

```html
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This will off course  work.My question is why its not working with numeric data. My problem is my service returns numeric data in an array.

Answer (score 5):

As of autocomplete widget expects an array of strings as a source, you can convert your data to array of strings on widget creation:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        1234,
        1456,
        1789,
        1988,  
    ];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags.map(function(a){
            return a.toString()
        })
    });
});
```